# How to use workflow commands in the page editor without opening workbox?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I've setup a basic workflow in Sitecore on my content items, the workflow states consists of Draft, Awaiting Approval and Approved (which proceeds to auto publish). In the Content Editor you can use the review tab to action commands within your workflow, so I can submit from the ribbon.

Is there an option in sitecore out-of-the-box to do this in the page editor without opening the workbox?

Ideally I'd like to have the submit command action in the page editor ribbon.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which version of **Sitecore** you use, but I do recommend updating your solution to the most current version (**Sitecore 6.6 update 3**). It does have **Submit** / **Approve** / **Reject** commands in the notification bar under the ribbon in Page Editor out of the box (see attached screenshots).

[image: Sitecore 6.6 update 3 - submit button in Page Editor]

[image: Sitecore 6.6 update 3 - approve and reject buttons in Page Editor]

Comment: Looks like this feature was added in sitecore 6.6 and we were running 6.5. Thank you for pointing that out!